# About exchangeable random variables

Tags: probability-theory

We have an infinite sequence of random variables which are exchangeable. Could we say that each finite subsequence of this sequence is again exchangeable?

Answer (score 4):

By definition, an infinite collection of random variables is said to be exchangeable if every finite subset of those variables is exchangeable. (See definition 1.11 in Schervich's book "[Theory of statistics](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~mark/advt/.index.html)" (p.7).

A finite collection of finite random variables is said to be exchangeable if their distribution is invariant under permutations.